# Is possible that make and save a .swf file?

Tags: flash, actionscript

I want to create a clip dynamically (for example with createEmptyMovieClip) and after assign object and motion to it, save or export it as a .swf file.

Is it possible?

Comment: Could you try to elaborate better your question?

Comment: yes, my project is that provide a swf file at web area, that users can make and generate a swf file with it.
i search at google and understand that it not possible.

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/Q_22582130.html

the solution is that use php.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible without utilizing some sort of server side solution, which doesn't seem to be a big deal in my opinion seeing as what a payoff you'd be getting.